# Bongard n°3: Illiterate

Tags: bongard

[image]

As usual, I'm adding the link to the rules for those that don't know the puzzles [Click me!](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html)

This one's easy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to me that

> The diagrams on the left have exactly one point of intersection of degree $3$ while those on the right have either a point of intersection of degree $4$ or two points of intersection of degree $3$. Here, the degree of a point of intersection is the number of curves emerging from it in any given direction.

See the following diagram, for illustration

> [image]